# How to map a derived class using an EntityBase class on FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

I have an EntityBase class for FluentNHibernate:

```
public abstract class EntityBase<T>
{
    public EntityBase()
    {

    }

    public static T GetById(int id)
    {
        return (T)Hibernate.Session.Get<T>(id);
    }
    public virtual void Save()
    {
        using (var transaction = Hibernate.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Hibernate.Session.SaveOrUpdate(this);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    public static IList<T> List()
    {
        return Hibernate.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
    }
    public static IList<T> ListTop(int i)
    {
        return Hibernate.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).SetMaxResults(i).List<T>();
    }
    public virtual void Delete()
    {
        using (var transaction = Hibernate.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Hibernate.Session.Delete(this);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a base member class also a table in database:

```
abstract public class BaseMember:EntityBase<BaseMember>
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string RecordDate { get; protected set; }

    public BaseMember()
    {

    }
}
```

I have another Member class that is deriving from BaseMember class:

```
public class IndividualMember : BaseMember
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressDefinition { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RecordDate { get; set; }

    public IndividualMember()
    {

    }
}
```

How can I map those classes with BaseMember and IndividualMember tables in db?

Comment: have a look at Castles Active Record which does the Baseentity stuff already: http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Active%20Record&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of Inheritance mapping strategies in Fluent NHibernate. 
You can use SubclassMap mapping for derived class.

Strategies : Table-per-class-hierarchy, Table-per-subclass and Table Per Concrete Class.

For table-per-class-hierarchy strategy, you just need to specify the discriminator column.

For more reference :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat
https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#wiki-subclasses